# Laravel validation with enum column

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

I have this fields:

> id, title, type

type is enum
And I would like to validate my title by Type column, eg:

```
id | title | type
1 | test | option1
2| test | option2
```

So when someone tries to insert a row with this condition, validation should be processed for unique of the column.

```
3 | test | option1 ==> should not be insert due unique validation rule.
```

How will my validation rule look like?

Regards

// Edit 1:
Rules facade was the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `type` field is not dynamic, you could use `Rule` class to add extra query in your validation rule.

```
return [
    'title' => [
        Rule::unique('tablename', 'title')->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('type', 'option1');
        })
    ]
];
```

else, you can make custom validation rules.

Answer (score 9):

***in:option1,option2***
The field under validation must be included in the given list of values.

***not_in:option1,option2***
The field under validation must not be included in the given list of values.

You'r validation should look like the following, but it requires your to hard code your options in "in" parameters or 'implode' an array.

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::only(['title', 'type']), [
    'type' => 'in:option1,option2, // option1 or option2 values
    'title' => 'required|min:6|max:255', //whatever rules you want ..
]);
```

You can avoid 'implode' by this way:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::only(['title', 'type']), [
        'type' => Rule::in(['option1', 'option2']), // option1 or option2 values
        'title' => 'required|min:6|max:255', //whatever rules you want ..
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no custom rule for that .

You can not verify combination of two columns as unique by any laravel native validation rule.

However you have got two options ahead:

1. Create your own rule using the a custom validator. [Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-validation-rules)
2. Use this package: https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator

Of course make combination of `title` and `type` unique in you migration as well.