# How to verify request with enum of database and table

Tags: php, laravel

So I am developing a web page where people can buy some t-shirts, and they can choose colors, size, and quantity, the problem is, that the user can edit the size and color on html source, so I need to validate if the size match with enum on database and the color with the colors available on the table! I need to do this on request validation, and so far I have this:

```
    return [
        'tam' => 'required',
        'color' => 'required',
        'quantity' => 'required|numeric|min:1|max:20',
    ];
```

And the page has this:

[image]

Database enum has this:

[image]

with the "tamanho" field as enum, how can I verify if the "tamanho" on webpage is one of the enum values from database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel IN Validation or Validation by ENUM Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976658/laravel-in-validation-or-validation-by-enum-values)

Comment: Also refer to this question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317806/laravel-validation-with-enum-column/45398621

Comment: @Abishek That okey, but how can I make it dynamically, so if the database changes, this changes to

Comment: I need to check dynamically the enum values

Comment: I am afraid, there isn't a good way to do this, unless and otherwise you create a custom rule that uses the Query Builder to query the `INFORMATION SCHEMA` and get the enum values dynamically and use it on the rule. That's just an overhead you don't want.

Comment: I think as suggested by @Abishek  first link will best suite. instead of accessing table information

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is one of the reasons ENUM is "evil". :) http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/

Keeping the ENUM, the solution is to query the ENUM values. Please refer to:
[How can I get enum possible values in a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350052/how-can-i-get-enum-possible-values-in-a-mysql-database)

The cleaner solution would be to store sizes in a separate table and reference them in your original table. This way you could use "normal" validation stuff.